# Error while publishing my application on Webmatrix. Error says "Cannot access a closed Stream"

Tags: azure, webmatrix

When trying to publish my php app to Ms Azure using Webmatrix I'm getting this error

Error Importing Azure Management Credentials
Cannot access a closed Stream.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Move to your Azure credit status dashboard(In your account in the azure website). Then click on the name of the item you want to use, then under Publish Your App, click Download the publish profile. Then in Webmatrix, click publish then choose, upload publishing profile. Then select the file you just that has just been downloaded.